# How can I ignore all warnings from included headers in clang/gcc?

Tags: gcc, clang, warnings

I want to use `#pragma clang diagnostic push` to ignore warnings from some included header files. So I write this:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
#include "SpinGenApi/SpinnakerGenApi.h"
#include "Spinnaker.h"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

But still the compiler prints warnings when compiling the file with this code. What do I need to change so that all warnings are ignored for these headers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer seems to be in this case that `-Wall` contrary to its name did not include the warnings which I wanted to suppress. I added `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Weverything"` as well and they went away.